# JS to PHP Foreach Array

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

Through Curl i can extract data from a site that is in js.

Here is the code in PHP,

```
$content = 'var locations = ["https:\/\/website.to\/embed-h7jg2gopxi0k.html","https:\/\/website1.to\/embed-v3ywuokxeirq-580x326.html","https:\/\/website3.to\/embed-dzl49jlbx1lw.html","https:\/\/website2.to\/embed-hovrbjkng4cm.html];';
```

How can i convert this to php and foreach links one by one.

Comment: Is "`var locations = `" a guaranteed constant prefix? Then it's pretty trivial to remove it and decode the rest as JSON…

Comment: "var locations = " can be removed through str_replace

Comment: OK, then you're pretty much set, no?

Comment: Here's a RegEx approach: http://ideone.com/2tSQLo

Comment: Or this can be done through extracting link inside "

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks It will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/s', $content, $match)) {     // get the array part
    $string = str_replace(array('"', '\\'), "", $match[1]);     // remove " and escapes - \
    $your_desired_array = explode(',', $string);     // explode string on ,
}

print_r($your_desired_array);
```